# Managing React Native Push Notifications across Multiple Devices with Shared User Accounts: Registration and Verification

Tags: react-native-push-notification

Managing React Native Push Notifications across Multiple Devices with Shared User Accounts Registration and Verification need to check if device is registered or not and also I need to have token for each user who ever logs in to device and when notification sends it should be sent for all devices for all users